# Apache POI: find characters in Word document without spaces

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to read the number of characters without spaces in a Word document using Apache POI.
I can get the number of characters with spaces using the `SummaryInformation.getCharCount()` method as in the following code:

```
public void countCharacters() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File wordFile = new File(BASE_PATH, "test.doc");
    POIFSFileSystem p = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(wordFile));
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(p);
    SummaryInformation props = doc.getSummaryInformation();
    int numOfCharsWithSpaces = props.getCharCount();
    System.out.println(numOfCharsWithSpaces);
}
```

However there seems to be no method for returning the number of characters without spaces. 
How do I find this value?

Comment: If you have the text of the document, do a `text.replaceAll("\\s","").length()`.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I don't have access to the text and would prefer to use the standard properties of the document. Word seems to store this information (if for example I open it in MS Word and go to File > Properties there is a field "Characters" that displays exactly the information I want, however it is not available from POI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to base this on the metadata of the document, all you will get is **estimates** (according to the Microsoft specs). There are essentially two values which you can play around with:

- [GKPIDSI_CHARCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd925819%28v=office.12%29.aspx#GKPIDSI_CHARCOUNT) (which is what you already accessed in your own code sample)
- [GKPIDDSI_CCHWITHSPACES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd945671%28v=office.12%29.aspx#GKPIDDSI_CCHWITHSPACES)

Don't ask me about the exact differences of those two values, though. I haven't designed this stuff...

Below is a code sample to illustrate the access to them (*GKPIDDSI_CCHWITHSPACES* is a little awkward):

```
HWPFDocument document = [...];
SummaryInformation summaryInformation = document.getSummaryInformation();
System.out.println("GKPIDSI_CHARCOUNT: " + summaryInformation.getCharCount());

DocumentSummaryInformation documentSummaryInformation = document.getDocumentSummaryInformation();
Integer count = null;
for (Property property : documentSummaryInformation.getProperties()) {
    if (property.getID() == 0x11) {
            count = (Integer) property.getValue();
            break;
        }       
    }       
System.out.println("GKPIDDSI_CCHWITHSPACES: " + count);
```

The moment at which Word's internal algorithm that updates those values kicks in is rather unpredictable to me. So what you see in Word's own statistics may not necessarily be the same as when running the above code.

Comment: Thanks for digging out this information! If you use a nightly build and/or a release after 3.14 beta 1, you'll now find [a handy getter for this character count with spaces](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/DocumentSummaryInformation.html#getCharCountWithSpaces%28%29) added based on your findings :)

Comment: @Gagravarr Cool! If I get bored I may even be tempted to add the [missing unit tests](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58847) for this...